# Pandas: Swap rows between columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Some rows were input in the wrong columns so now I need to swap them.

`df = pd.DataFrame({'c': {0: '22:58:00', 1: '23:03:00', 2: '0', 3: '10'}, 'a': {0: '0', 1: '10', 2: '22:58:00', 3: '23:03:00'}, 'd': {0: '23:27:00', 1: '23:39:00', 2: '10', 3: '17'}, 'b': {0: '10', 1: '17', 2: '23:27:00', 3: '23:39:00'}})`

```
          a         b         c         d
0         0        10  22:58:00  23:27:00
1        10        17  23:03:00  23:39:00
2  22:58:00  23:27:00         0        10
3  23:03:00  23:39:00        10        17
```

My current approach

```
cpy = df[['a', 'b']]
df.loc[2:, 'a'] = df['c']
df.loc[2:, 'b'] = df['d']
df.loc[2:, 'c'] = cpy['a']
df.loc[2:, 'd'] = cpy['b']
```

Expected output

```
    a   b         c         d
0   0  10  22:58:00  23:27:00
1  10  17  23:03:00  23:39:00
2   0  10  22:58:00  23:27:00
3  10  17  23:03:00  23:39:00
```

It works but this is only possible because it was 4 columns.
Is there a better way to do this?

Note the dtypes can cause issues with sorting
`df.loc[0]['c']` is `datetime.time(22, 58)`

Maybe there is something like

`df.swap_row_col(index=[2:], columns_from=['a', 'b'], columns_to=['c', 'd'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For swapping and separating `datetime.time` and `string` in your sample, you may use `applymap`, `np.argsort` and numpy indexing (Note: your numbers in sample are in string format, so I check type `str`)

```
arr = np.argsort(df.applymap(type).ne(str), 1).to_numpy()

Out[985]:
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 0, 1]], dtype=int32)

df_out = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy()[df.index[:,None], arr], columns=df.columns)

Out[989]:
    a   b         c         d
0   0  10  22:58:00  23:27:00
1  10  17  23:03:00  23:39:00
2   0  10  22:58:00  23:27:00
3  10  17  23:03:00  23:39:00
```

If you get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'`
replace `to_numpy` with `values`

Comment: ahh yes that worked, I had to replace `to_numpy` with `.values`

Comment: oh, I guess your pandas version < 0.24. `to_numpy` implemented in pandas 0.24+  :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1: `np.sort`

`np.sort` with `pd.DataFrame` constructor works for me:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.astype(str)), columns=df.columns)

    a   b         c         d
0   0  10  22:58:00  23:27:00
1  10  17  23:03:00  23:39:00
2   0  10  22:58:00  23:27:00
3  10  17  23:03:00  23:39:00
```

---

#### Method 2:

More general, by checking which rows match to your date pattern and vice versa and then swapping these values with `bfill` or `ffill`:

```
match_pattern = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'))

numeric = df.where(~match_pattern).bfill(axis=1).dropna(how='any', axis=1)
dates = df.where(match_pattern).ffill(axis=1).dropna(how='any', axis=1)

df = pd.concat([numeric, dates], axis=1)

    a   b         c         d
0   0  10  22:58:00  23:27:00
1  10  17  23:03:00  23:39:00
2   0   0  23:27:00  23:27:00
3  10  10  23:39:00  23:39:00
```

Comment: sorting issue `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < datetime.time()`

Comment: Ahh mixed type columns. Gonna be hard to sort this. Unless you convert it to string. See edit of my answer.

Comment: Added new method, can you check this? @ksooklall

Comment: `TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`, match_pattern is all `NaN`

Comment: again, you have to use `df.astype(str)` first, else its quite hard to compare `dates` with `int` dont you agree?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we can try notice here in my solution if the original order is 100, 0 my out put still 100, 0

```
df=pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key= lambda s: ':' in s),1).tolist(),columns=df.columns)
Out[119]: 
     c   a         d         b
0    0  10  22:58:00  23:27:00
1   10  17  23:03:00  23:39:00
2  100  10  22:58:00  23:27:00
3   10  17  23:03:00  23:39:00
```

Comment: your solution is having issues with the datetime object `TypeError: ("argument of type 'datetime.time' is not iterable", 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: @ksooklall I create the dataframe by using your code ,

Comment: Same problem -_- @YOandBEN_W

Comment: @Erfan ummmm seems like sample can not address the real problem

Comment: +1, more safe and general than mine. Wish there was a `pandas` sort method where we could specify `key` like in the `sorted` function.

Comment: @Erfan that's pretty much what I am looking for, I guess there isn't any